# Image Magic convert svg to png issue

Tags: svg, png, imagemagick-convert

I have installed ImageMagick on My OS X 10.9.1 by using following

```
brew install wget
brew update
brew cleanup
brew doctor
brew link libpng freetype
brew install imagemagick
brew install ghostscript
```

convert -density 300 test.svg -resize 1040x1090 test.png 
now when I am converting my svg to png , text used in svg got changed, font family is changed, font got stretched,

But when i installed ImageMagick on My Windows it works fine,

So can any one please help me out in this

[SVG File is here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/18190667/37.svg)

Comment: Windows uses librsvg. I don't know how to do that with brew but 'linking?' librsvg will probably fix it.

Answer (score 1):

That file uses the font "Gautami".  Do you perhaps have that font installed on your Windows box, but not your Mac?  On the other hand, it should default to something sensible, so if it it doing something weird on Mac, perhaps that is a bug in ImageMagick.  You may want to report that.

One possible fix is to open the SVG file in a text editor and replace references to "Gautami" with another font name, like "Arial" or something.  Or use the generic "sans-serif".